# How do I access a variable declared inside an if-block?

Tags: java, variables

I have this code:

```
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    final Action action = event.getAction();
    if (action == Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK){
        Location l1 = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
    } else if (action == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
        Location l2 = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
    }

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000*60*60);
                    //Insert code here
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

How do I access `l1` from `//insert code here`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just declare `l1` outside of the `if` block, otherwise it's local to that block.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, unless you declare it outside your if block.

With your current code the variable named `l1` is accessible from exactly one line.

It shouldn't be defined within an if block if you want to use it outside of it.

**Also**, you'll have to declare the variable as final if you want to use it inside your thread.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually two issues you are dealing with:

1. The variable `l1` should be moved outside of the the if block (so `l1` isn't out of scope at the point you want to use it).
2. `l1` must be final.  An inner class will not use a non-final variable, since the variable must be *copied* to the inner class instance.

Answer (score 2):

I generally stick with the best practice (especially if you're going to use the variable outside the IF block), is to declare variables at the top of methods.

Or do something like this...

```
Location loc; 
if (action == Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK){
    loc = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
} else if (action == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
    loc = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but why are you useing a conditional block if you use the same method invocation chain in both cases?

I'd change your code as follows:

```
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    final Location l = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000*60*60);
                    //Insert code here
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

Or if there are more else-if conditions you should use Location like this:

```
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    final Action action = event.getAction();
    final Location l = null;

    if (action == Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK){
        l = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
    } else if (action == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
        l = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
    }

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000*60*60);
                    //Insert code here
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

But then again... maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that vriables are generally available in the cope where there are created. But they can be usually set in any scope with that scope.

So try this

```
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) { 

    final Action action = event.getAction(); 
    Location l1; // Created at function scope
    Location l2;  
    if (action == Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK){ 
         l1 = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();  // l1 available here
    } else if (action == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) { 
         l2 = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();  // l1 available here
    } 


    and l1 & l2 available here and below
    .
    .
    .

} // l1 & l2 go out of scrope here.
```

Also you should consdider that l1 & l2 are not both needed now as only one gets set dure to the left or roght click.

Comment: They are available but with your code they are not necessary initialized so you can't use them.

Comment: true... there should be a null check